# PHP: What does an error >0 mean in Multiple File upload

Tags: php, file, debugging

My PHP upload file code is generating an error, randomly, after I changed NOTHING about the code.  I did edit the PHP.ini file... but then I changed it back and now my file upload system is broken for no reason.  I've simplified the error generated to this example:

```
$count =0;    
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename){
echo ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$count]);
$count+=1;

}
```

is producing "1" as an error for a valid file.  If I knew what "1" meant, I think I'd be able to fix the issue.  How can I determine what the error is?  As I mentioned, I have changed absolutely nothing about the code, which was working a minute ago and is now not working.

Comment: Is the file maybe too large? Check your php.ini if your `upload_max_filesize` is set properly and high enough.

Comment: Properly you forget to restart your Apache **/etc/init.d/apache2 restart**

Comment: Take a look here for the codes. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php and for reference error code 1 is.... `Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.`

Comment: File is not too large (2mb), upload_max_filesize was not set in php.ini before and it was working fine.  Right now, it is not set at all.

Comment: Alright, I should have mentioned this but for people in the future freaking out about multiple file uploads, I'll mention it now.  I am using GoDaddy and shared hosting accounts dont have access to some of the filepaths/commands people would normally use with SSH, so SSH is worthless.

In GoDaddy though, in CPanel, under Software, there's an option to kill processes.  I did this and my PHP script worked with edited PHP.ini.

Thanks to everyone for leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I should have mentioned this but for people in the future freaking out about multiple file uploads, I'll mention it now. I am using GoDaddy and shared hosting accounts dont have access to some of the filepaths/commands people would normally use with SSH, so SSH is worthless. In GoDaddy though, in CPanel, under Software, there's an option to kill processes. I did this and my PHP script worked with edited PHP.ini. Thanks to everyone for leading me in the right direction – user2954658